# How to find the five most common elements in an array of objects and total them using .reduce()

Tags: javascript, reduce

For school, I need to find the most common genres in a list of book objects. I *must* use reduce() to create a new object and total the number of books in that genre. The expected output looks like this

```
  [
    { name: "Nonfiction", count: 9 },
    { name: "Historical Fiction", count: 7 },
    { name: "Thriller", count: 7 },
    ...
  ]
```

The book list contains **many** book objects like this.

```
books = [
{
      id: "5f447132320b4bc16f950076",
      title: "est voluptate nisi",
      genre: "Classics",
      authorId: 12,
      author: {
        id: 12,
        name: {
          first: "Chrystal",
          last: "Lester",
        }
    }
},
{
      id: "5f447132320b4bc16f950176",
      title: "The Name of the Wind",
      genre: "Fantasy",
      authorId: 10,
      author: {
        id: 10,
        name: {
          first: "Patrick",
          last: "Rothfuss",
        }
    }
}

]
```

Once again I must use the reduce function to do this.
This is what I have as of now

```
function mostCommonGenres(books) {
  let values = Object.values(books)
  let total = 0
  
  const genres = values.reduce((acc, val) => {

    let {id,title,genre,authorId,borrows} = val

  return {...acc, ['name']: genre, ...acc, ['count']: total++}
}, {})
  return genres
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't iterate through every object just the first one. Also the total variable is always the length of the array -1.

Comment: do you have tried something? what does not work?

Comment: Yes. I have just edited my post to contain what I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

First let's create 2 helper functions:

The first one is to group items in an array using a given key, i.e.:

```
/**
 * Helper function to group items in an array using the given key
 * 
 * @param {*} array 
 * @param {*} key 
 */
function groupByKey(array, key) {
  return array
    .reduce((hash, obj) => {
      if(obj[key] === undefined) return hash; 
      return Object.assign(hash, { [obj[key]]:( hash[obj[key]] || [] ).concat(obj)})
    }, {});
}
```

The second one is to get the size of an object, i.e.:

```
/**
 * Helper function to get the size of an object
 * 
 * @param {*} obj 
 */
Object.size = function(obj) {
  var size = 0, key;
  for (key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
  }
  return size;
};
```

Given our list of books, i.e.:

```
/**
 * List of books
 */
books = [
  {
    id: "5f447132320b4bc16f950076",
    title: "est voluptate nisi",
    genre: "Classics",
    authorId: 12,
    author: {
      id: 12,
      name: {
        first: "Chrystal",
        last: "Lester",
      }
    }
  },
  {
    id: "5f447132320b4bc16f950176",
    title: "The Name of the Wind",
    genre: "Fantasy",
    authorId: 10,
    author: {
      id: 10,
      name: {
        first: "Patrick",
        last: "Rothfuss",
      }
    }
  }
];
```

This is how we will use our helper functions:

```
/**
 * Group all books using genre
 */
const genres = groupByKey(books, 'genre');

// Initialize empty array to hold results
let results = [];

/**
 * Create new object with genre & count
 */
for (const key in genres) {
  results.push({
    name: key,
    count: Object.size(genres[key]),
  })
}

/**
 * Echo results to view the results
 */
console.log(results);
```

Here's the full code in one file:

```
/**
 * Helper function to group items in an array using the given key
 * 
 * @param {*} array 
 * @param {*} key 
 */
function groupByKey(array, key) {
  return array
    .reduce((hash, obj) => {
      if(obj[key] === undefined) return hash; 
      return Object.assign(hash, { [obj[key]]:( hash[obj[key]] || [] ).concat(obj)})
    }, {});
}

/**
 * Helper function to get the size of an object
 * 
 * @param {*} obj 
 */
Object.size = function(obj) {
  var size = 0, key;
  for (key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
  }
  return size;
};


/**
 * List of books
 */
books = [
  {
    id: "5f447132320b4bc16f950076",
    title: "est voluptate nisi",
    genre: "Classics",
    authorId: 12,
    author: {
      id: 12,
      name: {
        first: "Chrystal",
        last: "Lester",
      }
    }
  },
  {
    id: "5f447132320b4bc16f950176",
    title: "The Name of the Wind",
    genre: "Fantasy",
    authorId: 10,
    author: {
      id: 10,
      name: {
        first: "Patrick",
        last: "Rothfuss",
      }
    }
  }
];

/**
 * Group all books using genre
 */
const genres = groupByKey(books, 'genre');

// Initialize empty array to hold result
let results = [];

/**
 * Create new object with genre & count
 */
for (const key in genres) {
  results.push({
    name: key,
    count: Object.size(genres[key]),
  })
}

/**
 * Echo results
 */
console.log(results);
```